# Document has to be loaded only with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, redirect

I work on my `localhost` and use the latest jQuery version.

I have a page in the root directory (/) which is `"index.php"`. And inside of index.php, i run my javascript codes like `"load()"`. For instance, there is another directory called `"/video"` and there is an `"index.php"` file inside of it too.
So, I load the `"/video/index.php"` into my div `(main-container)` in main page with pushState method. So, the url changes from `"localhost/"` to `"localhost/video"` but the page is not redirected or reloaded.

Finally, my problem is that the whole code works properly when I load from main `"index.php"`, but when I go to the exact URL *(e.g.: `"localhost/video"`)* it only shows the page itself. What I want to see is the main page which shows the loaded `"localhost/video/index.php"`.

OR: for another point of view: How can I make the `"/video/index.php"` page redirect to `"index.php"` and load itself there?

Here is my code which does the action:

```
$("#nav-wrapper a").click(function(preventLinks){
    href = $(this).attr("href");

    $("#main-container").load(href);

    history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
    preventLinks.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an if statement at the top of your `video/index.php` file which checks to see if the request is an XHR. If it is not, redirect to the main page. You'll also need to check if the request was redirected on the home page. You can do that on the client side with a hash portion of the URL.

video/index.php:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
    strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' ) {
    //request is ajax, serve normal page
} else {
    redirect('/#video/index.php');
}
?>
```

/index.php:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if(window.location.hash){
            var href = window.location.hash;
            $('#main-container').load(href);
            history.pushState('','New URL: '+href, href);
        } else {
            //do normal stuff
            $("#nav-wrapper a").click(function(preventLinks){
                href = $(this).attr("href");

                $("#main-container").load(href);

                history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
                preventLinks.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

An alternative strategy would be to serve the entire root page WITH the video contents in the #main-container. That would make it so you don't have to detect the hash portion of the URL and your main page HTML and javascript can stay the same.